# Restkit / AFNetworking stripping out an empty param on multipart POST

Tags: ios, afnetworking, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to post to my webservice using RestKit using the below method:

```
(NSMutableURLRequest *)multipartFormRequestWithObject:(id)object
                                                 method:(RKRequestMethod)method
                                                   path:(NSString *)path
                                             parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                              constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
```

Everything works great until one the parameters contains a key/value with an array that is empty. For example `@"friends" : @"0 objects"`<-(empty array)

Stepping though the code it appears this function in `AFNetworking` is stripping out the empty parameters from even being added to the multipart request. How can I prevent this from happening? I'm sure I'm not the only one that has run into this issue. I guess a work around could be to add another call to the API with the parameter, but to me that seems like I shouldn't have to resort to that.

```
   NSArray * AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue(NSString *key, id value)
```

********* EDIT ***********

Ok so I have investigated this further, the problem appears to be when the parameters are converted to an array. The function calls itself recursively:

```
 [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[]", key], nestedValue)];
```

When it does and you have a parameter that was an empty array, the value passed to the recursive call is an empty array. So when it gets to this section of code:

```
 } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSArray *array = value;
            for (id nestedValue in array) {
                [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[]", key], nestedValue)];
            }
```

`for(id nestedValue in Array)` sees an empty array so skips over the rest of the code. There is no nested value to add. Essentially it is striping out a parameter that may contain an empty array. Below is the full function.

```
NSArray * AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue(NSString *key, id value) {
    NSMutableArray *mutableQueryStringComponents = [NSMutableArray array];

    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = value;
        // Sort dictionary keys to ensure consistent ordering in query string, which is important when deserializing potentially ambiguous sequences, such as an array of dictionaries
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

        NSArray *array = [dictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ sortDescriptor ]];
        for (id nestedKey in array) {
            id nestedValue = [dictionary objectForKey:nestedKey];
            if (nestedValue) {
                [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue((key ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%@]", key, nestedKey] : nestedKey), nestedValue)];
            }
        }
    } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSArray *array = value;
        for (id nestedValue in array) {
            [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[]", key], nestedValue)];
        }
    } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]]) {
        NSSet *set = value;
        for (id obj in set) {
            [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue(key, obj)];
        }
    } else {
        [mutableQueryStringComponents addObject:[[AFQueryStringPair alloc] initWithField:key value:value]];
    }

    return mutableQueryStringComponents;
}
```

Comment: Where are you finding that `AFNetworking` is stripping out parameters? The `AFURLRequestSerialization` class seem to throw an assert for nil content (body) but appears to properly process non-null, yet empty body. Even so, isn't `@"friends" : @""` an acceptable solution?

Comment: In the method I posted above it appears the parameters all key / value go into the request, but the returned content does not include the friends parameters. Going to investigate it further.

Comment: Sorry the second part of your comment is not acceptable in this case as it is an array and that would be a string, the JSON parsing wouldn't be correct.

Comment: Are you actually using RestKit mapping and it's a problem, or are you calling `multipartFormRequestWithObject:` and adding parameters which is the problem? In either case, you are unlikely to be using AFN2 and RK2 as they are incompatible. Please be clear on what you are using.

Comment: @Wain Is RK2 not using AFN2? I thought it was, my mistake if not. I'm calling multipartFormRequestWithObject and passing the parameters to it. In the function above, it appears to be stripping out and parameters with empty arrays

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the NSDictionary *parameters? Are you sure you're not adding a nil object when you create the NSDictionary that is terminating the NSDictionary creation at that point?

Comment: @CharlesA Yes I've inspected the object and it is not nil. The dictionary would prevent adding a nil object before it got to that function in the first place. Getting back to working on this today, so will post more details.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue using AfNetworking2.0,
I init NSMutableArray like below to avoid the problem:

`NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[[NSNull null]]];`